# Parsing JSON and then removing the nodes based on some value

Tags: json

My requirement is that I will need to parse a *JSON*.
That *JSON* contains some specific value (Like for example `FIELDTOBEDELETED`).

Which elements will have value `FIELDTOBEDELETED`, those elements should be deleted from that *JSON*.

Can anybody please help me?

It would be great if the code is based on *JSON* iter.
But any other suggestion is also appreciated.

The sample *JSON*:

```
{
    "customer": [{
            "rmCustomerKey": "cu_0000",
            "billAccAssignmentRules": [{
                    "priceTypes": ["any"],
                    "validFor": {
                        "start": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.00+02:00"
                    },
                    "tmpAccountId": "ba_0000"
                }
            ],
            "validFor": {
                "start": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.00+02:00"
            },
            "homeTimeZones": [{
                    "validFor": {
                        "start": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.00+02:00"
                    },
                    "timeZone": "Europe\/Prague"
                }
            ],
            "externalId": "FIELDTOBEDELETED",
            "statuses": [{
                    "validFor": {
                        "start": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.00+02:00"
                    },
                    "status": "CustomerActive"
                }
            ],
            "billingAccounts": "FIELDTOBEDELETED",
            "party": {
                "partyId": "pr_0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: Please share the JOSN.

Comment: I have shared it now...

Comment: @SuvenduGhosh you tried anything to do this. If please share the code.

Comment: using which programming language are you trying to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

I have found one solution.
The original json is going to be very very big.
Parsing all the node then checking the value and deleting the node will really have performance impact.

So I have used regular expression to delete from the json string like below.

String regEx = "([^\d.^,^\[^\{])+"+JSONExpressions.DELETE_FIELD_TAG+"\"+,?";
json = json.replaceAll(regEx, "");

Thanks,
Suvendu